Bootstrap tagsinput text returns to the input after tag is created
I am using bootstrap tagsinput and running into an issue where after a custom tag is created, the text previously entered returns to the search box when focus changes.
Edit: updated to have a minimum example, and it seems that it wasn't anything I was trying to add, but has to do with using custom tags alongside typeaheadjs. Adding tags from the prepopulated list is fine, but just typing something like "test" and hitting enter adds it as a tag, but as soon as you click somewhere else the text "test" appears in the search box again. below is the code I was using, you would need to update the script tags to reference the right files.
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/bootstrap-tagsinput/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/bootstrap-tagsinput/src/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/bootstrap-tagsinput/src/bootstrap-tagsinput.css">
<script>

$(function() {

var citynames = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: {
    url: 'lib/bootstrap-tagsinput/citynames.json',
    filter: function(list) {
      return $.map(list, function(cityname) {
        return { name: cityname }; });
    }
  }
});
citynames.initialize();

$('input').tagsinput({
  typeaheadjs: {
    name: 'citynames',
    displayKey: 'name',
    valueKey: 'name',
    source: citynames.ttAdapter()
  }
});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type='search'   />
</body> 


Post code as a [mcve] (hint: click the brackets button <>). Include the HTML, load the plugin as well.
